# Calling functions inside generator functions, but "Generator is already running"

Tags: javascript

I am coding a project for a simple football game in JavaScript. When a player hikes the ball, I am attempting to run a series of functions in order to validate a legal snap. To do this, I am using a generator function, so that I can organize all the functions that run, as the order in which they run is important. Essentially, I run the generator function once using the snap() function, and then at the conclusion of each Check() function, I either return validateSnap.next() if it is a legal snap, or a fail function to exit out of the generator and handle an illegal snap. Here is a simplified version of my code below:

```
function* snapProtocol() {
  yield check1();
  yield check2();
  yield check3();
  yield check4();
  yield check5();
  yield play();
}

let validateSnap = snapProtocol()

function snap() {
  validateSnap.next();
}

function check1() {
  let meetsCriteria = true;
  if (meetsCriteria) {
    validateSnap.next();
  } else {
    handleError();
  }
}
```

I am receiving a "Generator is already running" error. I presume this is because the check1 function has not finished, but when I add a callback function, I get the same error. Why is this occurring? Is there a simpler method to accomplish this? Previously, I would run each check function and then have it return either a true or false value, with true if it was a legal snap to go to the next check function, or false to stop the execution of the initial function. This required to me declare a bunch of variables as well as have an if statement after every function, so I was looking for a cleaner approach.

Comment: The generator is attempting to yield the value of `check1` but then `check1` calls `.next()` in the meantime. I am quite confused how this code is supposed to work. You're not even using the value that the generator yields. What is the intention here? What is supposed to happen?

Answer (score 0):

You are try to call `next()` inside check function which is in progress. You can't call `next()` during this function end. Shortly you can not call `next()` inside function which is returned from generator.

Maybe this example can be helpful.

```js
function* snapProtocol() {
    yield check1();
    yield check1();
    yield check1();
    yield check1();
    yield check1();
}

let validateSnap = snapProtocol();

function snap() {
     
    let result = null
    do {
        result = validateSnap.next()
  
        if ( result.done ) {
            // all creterias was meet and play could be call
            break;
        }
    
        if ( result.value ) {
            // meets criteria and cen check another one
            continue
        } else {
            // doesn't meet createria and somthing should happend here
            break;
        }
      
    } while( !result.done )
}

function check1() {
    let meetsCriteria = true
    if (meetsCriteria) {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't really see how a generator function helps. `const checks = [ check1, check2, check3, check4, check5];` later `if (checks.every(x => x()) play(); else handle();` seems vastly easier than dealing with the generator result.

Comment: I agree with you. I only wanted to provide solution which is near what he try :)